# How do you fix React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a website with React and I have no idea how to solve this problem.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const generateToken = async () => {
      try {
        const token = await commerce.checkout.generateToken(cart.id, { type: 'cart' });

        setCheckoutToken(token);
      } catch (error) {
        history.pushState('/');
      }
    }

    generateToken();
  }, [cart]);
```

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'history'. Either include it or remove the
dependency array

Comment: window.history?

Comment: Please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: what is history? It looks you are not using react-router history which do not have `pushState` method rather `push`.

Comment: use eslint-plugin-react-hooks. It auto loads the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `history` in the `useEffect` dependency array. Now `useEffect` callback function will run everytime any item in the dependency array changes. Now as `history` or `window.history` is a browser provided API hence that will not change, so you can include that in your dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const generateToken = async () => {
      try {
        const token = await commerce.checkout.generateToken(cart.id, { type: 'cart' });

        setCheckoutToken(token);
      } catch (error) {
        history.pushState('/');
      }
    }

    generateToken();
  }, [cart, history]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading more about how useEffect() and its dependency array(s) work.
but if you wanted to get rid of that small warning:

```
    const generateToken = async () => {
      try {
        const token = await commerce.checkout.generateToken(cart.id, { type: 'cart' });

        setCheckoutToken(token);
      } catch (error) {
        history.pushState('/');
      }
    }

    generateToken();
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [cart]);
```

For more information:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Short version: linter is telling you that some state is depending on an external variable that can change (with history), but you are leaving it out from the dependency array of the useEffect(). For example; when the dependency array is empty, the effect will just run one time (per each component mount / 'page [re]load').
(please correct me if I'm wrong)